# Site scrape discord bot (first for me)

Tags: discord, discord.py

Trying to make a discord bot that will alert me when a color option is avalible. I can get BeautifulSoup to scrape the site and return a value in its own script but I am unable to get discord to alert. The bot does show online and I have enabled permissions.

```
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Discord bot token
TOKEN = 'Mine'

# Channel ID where you want to receive notifications
CHANNEL_ID = 'Mine'

# Website URL to monitor
WEBSITE_URL = 'https://www.stanley1913.com/products/adventure-quencher-travel-tumbler-40-oz'

# Initialize the Discord client
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name}')

@client.event
async def check_color():
    # Send a GET request to the website URL
    response = requests.get(WEBSITE_URL)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the HTML content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Extract the inventory count elements (modify as per website structure)
        color_swatches = soup.find_all('label', class_=("variant__button-label color-swatch color-swatch--pool",
                                                        "variant__button-label color-swatch color-swatch--tigerlily"))

        # Check if the desired color swatches are available
        if any(color_swatch['for'] == 'tigerlily' for color_swatch in color_swatches):
            # Get the Discord channel
            channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)

            # Send a notification
            await channel.send(f'New inventory available: {WEBSITE_URL}')
        else:
            print('Desired color swatches not found.')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to fetch website. Status code: {response.status_code}')

# Run the bot
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Everything I could think of and all of my googling couldnt fix my issue.

Comment: In the `else` statements, do you *want* to use `print()`? It will say "application did not respond" if you don't state anything in the chances that nothing happens.

Comment: How are you triggering the `check_color` event?

Comment: Considering it is not working, I am using the @client.event async def check_color():

Comment: @LuckElixir print is what I used in a mock site scrape using BeautifulSoup and it returned results. I am now trying to integrate it with Discord. If there is a better option I am open.

Comment: `print` returns it to the console, you want the bot to send something to your account. In that case, you would still use `channel.send`. That would also mean that you will have to define the channel beforehand.

Using `@client.event` only triggers when an event in the [docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/events.html) happens. 

If you want to use a command to check whether there is new stock, then you will have to use `@client.command`, and set your prefix.